# GluonMobile could not display non-English characters on android

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

It is ok on windows platform. But on android, non-English characters could not be correctly displayed. I checked the project setting, it is set "UTF-8". What should I do?

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` file and the relevant part of the code related to the issue, so we can try to reproduce it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply. I create the project from template "Gluon Mobile - Single View Project", and do not modify the build.gradle file.
I just modify the BasicView class, to add some Chinese characters:

```
public BasicView(String name)
{
    super(name);
    Label label = new Label("Hello 中文");
    ...
}
```

The "中文" is shown correctly on Windows, but can not show on Android.

Comment: See the answer for the follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062355/gluonmobile-has-font-bug-on-android-os)