# gluonmobile has font bug on android os

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I created a demo project on github.com to show this bug:
https://github.com/ismlsmile/TestGluonMobile

The project is created by the template "Gluon Mobile - Single View Project", and I only modify the text in BasicView.java, to add some chinese characters:

1.Windows.png: It is ok on Windows

2.Android.png: Chinese character can not show on Android

It is likely that a font bug.

Answer (score 1):

By default Gluon Mobile uses Roboto font, which doesn't include Chinese characters.

One easy way you can solve this issue is by setting any of the Android system fonts that do include them.

Using `Font.getFamilies()` on my Android device I discovered this one: `Noto Sans CJK SC Regular`. Probably you will have that too, or if not, another similar family.

So you can easily create a css file (`src/main/resources/style.css`) with this content:

```
.view {
    -fx-font-family: "Noto Sans CJK SC Regular";
}
```

and then load it in your view:

```
public BasicView(String name) {
    super(name);

    getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());
    ...
}
```

That should work.

[image]

**EDIT**

In order to apply the font to the `AppBar` as well, the css has to be set to the Scene, as this control is not part of the view.

In the MobileApplication class:

```
@Override
public void postInit(Scene scene) {
    Swatch.BLUE.assignTo(scene);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());
}
```

Then you'll need to apply the font to the `root`, and all the different controls that make use of a different font, like the `AppBar`:

```
.root,
.app-bar > .title-box > .label {
    -fx-font-family: "Noto Sans CJK SC Regular";
}
```

Note that you can use [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) to find out about the style classes for those controls.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I modify the project, add the css, and now it is ok for normal text, but the text in AppBar still has problem. I updated the project on github, and update the android image.

Comment: I've edited my answer. In short, you need to apply css to the Scene, and to the different controls that use a custom font, like the AppBar.