# gluon mobile iOS application localization - Japanese characters garbled

Tags: ios, localization, cjk, gluon

I am working on an application with both English and Japanese language support. When I run the app from IntelliJ IDEA on my Mac, both languages display without problem. However, after installing on my iPhone and doing mvn -Pios gluonFX:nativerun from the ide (with the phone connected to my computer) the app runs fine, but the Japanese characters just appear as boxes or a series of horizontal lines.

There are no errors during the build, package, or install, that I can identify. I have set the property file encoding to UTF-8 in IntelliJ. I have tried changing the fonts from System to Hiragino sans.

If there is anything else that would be relevant to solving the problem, please let me know and I will edit the question.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Sion

[screen shot of view showing garbled characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRMkK.png)

Here is a section of the presenter for this view:

```
@FXML
    void engToggleClick(){
        config.setCurrentLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        DrawerManager.buildDrawer(AppManager.getInstance());
        updateLanguage();
    }

    @FXML
    void jaToggleClick(){
        config.setCurrentLocale(Locale.JAPANESE);
        DrawerManager.buildDrawer(AppManager.getInstance());
        updateLanguage();
    }

    private void updateLanguage(){
        langs = ResourceBundle.getBundle("lang", config.getCurrentLocale());
                AppManager.getInstance().getAppBar().setTitleText(langs.getString("settingsappbar.text"));
        langSetLabel.setText(langs.getString("langsetlabel.text"));
        viewModeSetLabel.setText(langs.getString("viewmodelabel.text"));
        lightModeToggleBtn.setText(langs.getString("lightmodeset.text"));
        darkModeToggleBtn.setText(langs.getString("darkmodeset.text"));
    }
```

Here is the fxml for the view shown in the screen shot:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ToggleButtonGroup?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<View fx:id="settings" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="350.0" stylesheets="@settings.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/18" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.maplesunbook.views.SettingsPresenter">
   <center>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="langSetLabel" text="%langsetlabel.text">
               <font>
                  <Font name="HiraMinProN-W3" size="18.0" />
               </font>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </Label>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <ToggleButtonGroup selectionType="SINGLE">
                      <toggles>
                          <ToggleButton fx:id="engToggleBtn" onAction="#engToggleClick" text="ENG | 英語">
                              <graphic>
                                  <Icon content="LANGUAGE" />
                              </graphic>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="HiraMinProN-W3" size="13.0" />
                           </font>
                          </ToggleButton>
                          <ToggleButton fx:id="jaToggleBtn" onAction="#jaToggleClick" selected="true" text="JA | 日本語">
                              <graphic>
                                  <Icon content="LANGUAGE" />
                              </graphic>
                           <font>
                              <Font name="Hiragino Sans CNS W3" size="13.0" />
                           </font>
                          </ToggleButton>
                      </toggles>
                  </ToggleButtonGroup>
               </children>
            </HBox>
            <Label fx:id="viewModeSetLabel" layoutX="130.0" layoutY="196.0" text="%viewmodelabel.text">
               <font>
                  <Font name="Hiragino Sans CNS W3" size="18.0" />
               </font>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="10.0" />
               </padding>
            </Label>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="274.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <children>
                  <ToggleButtonGroup selectionType="SINGLE">
                     <toggles>
                        <ToggleButton fx:id="lightModeToggleBtn" onAction="#lightToggleClick" text="%lightmodeset.text">
                           <graphic>
                              <Icon content="BRIGHTNESS_HIGH" />
                           </graphic>
                        </ToggleButton>
                        <ToggleButton fx:id="darkModeToggleBtn" onAction="#darkToggleClick" selected="true" text="%darkmodeset.text">
                           <graphic>
                              <Icon content="BRIGHTNESS_1" />
                           </graphic>
                        </ToggleButton>
                     </toggles>
                  </ToggleButtonGroup>
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </center>
</View>
```

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.maplesunbook</groupId>
    <artifactId>Gluon-DateCon</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>Gluon-DateCon</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
        <attach.version>4.0.16</attach.version>
        <gluonfx.plugin.version>1.0.16</gluonfx.plugin.version>
        <javafx.plugin.version>0.0.8</javafx.plugin.version>
        <mainClassName>com.maplesunbook.GluonApplication</mainClassName>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
            <artifactId>charm-glisten</artifactId>
            <version>6.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>display</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>statusbar</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>storage</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.gluonhq.attach</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>${attach.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Gluon</id>
            <url>https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${javafx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.gluonhq</groupId>
                <artifactId>gluonfx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gluonfx.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <target>${gluonfx.target}</target>
                    <attachList>
                        <list>display</list>
                        <list>lifecycle</list>
                        <list>statusbar</list>
                        <list>storage</list>
                    </attachList>
                    <reflectionList>
                        <list>com.maplesunbook.views.ConverterPresenter</list>
                        <list>com.maplesunbook.views.SettingsPresenter</list>
                        <list>javafx.scene.control.DatePicker</list>
                    </reflectionList>
                    <bundlesList>
                        <list>lang_en</list>
                        <list>lang_ja</list>
                    </bundlesList>
                    <graalvmHome>/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-svm-java17-darwin-gluon-22.1.0.1-Final/Contents/Home</graalvmHome>
                    <mainClass>${mainClassName}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ios</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>ios</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>android</id>
            <properties>
                <gluonfx.target>android</gluonfx.target>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Comment: Maybe you can try changing the font, like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42062355/gluonmobile-has-font-bug-on-android-os ? Also you might need to set your locale, see this [issue](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluonfx-maven-plugin/issues/389).

Comment: @JoséPereda Thank you for your suggestions. I tried changing the fonts to Hiragino Sans W4, and added the <nativeImageArgs> <arg>-H:IncludeLocales=en,ja</arg></nativeImageArgs> to the configuration of the GluonFX-maven-plugin section of the pom. I still find that the Japanese characters are garbled when I set the locale to Locale.JAPANESE using a toggle button group in my settings view.

Comment: ＠José Pereda If you have any other suggestions, I would really appreciate it. Or if there is any other information I can provide, please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure that font (Hiragino Sans W4) is available on your phone? Did you list and log `Font.getFamilies()` ? It can be useful to have a ComboBox filled with those fonts, and then you can iterate over them and see if any work.

Comment: @JoséPereda Thanks for your help! I followed your suggest and was surprised to find that there is just one font (PingFang HK) that displayed Japanese characters correctly on my iPhone.